# How can I have door latch hardware at different heights on each side?

Tags: doors

Has anybody ever figured out a way to have a door handle at a different height inside and outside of a door and work the same latch. I have a door coming down steps I would like to have the handle higher but still have the other side match the handle height in the rooms. I've been playing around with ideas of mortising the side of the door so I can attach the 2 handles with flat bar stock and then fitting a piece back in. Just curious what anyone thinks or if anyone has ever done something like this.

Comment: I don't understand your plan. You'd need a gear- or chain-driven connection to operate the latch bolt from the misaligned handle.

Comment: Is the door in the middle of the staircase or simply at the top of the stairs?

Answer (score 2):

(Note that this door location isn't up to code. I'm assuming your house is rather old, but if it's not, it's indicative of other problems.)

Do you need the door to actually latch? If not, you could get 1 "ball catch" or "roller catch", and 2 dummy door knobs. Instead of actually turning the doorknob, you just push/pull the door open. The catch keeps the door closed until it's forced open.

Comment: I would like it to latch and lock. The ball catch is the standard. I was trying to get creative with an offset handle that actually works. And code isn't really an issue. I haven't even heard of an instance where it was an issue with code enforcement for a home sale.

Answer (score 2):

I might suggest a linkage system, assuming you don't mind having a lever actuator at least on the offset side of the door.  Drill a hole in the end of the existing (lever) handle, put in a linchpin or equivalent, connect to a vertical bar; do the same X inches down to a faux-lever handle.  This lower handle is then mounted to a pin or axle where the latch mech normally would go.

[image]